Sort version number of format 1.1.1 in Django
I have a Django model with a release_version char field that stores version information in the format 1.1.1 (e.g., 1.2.3). I need to sort a queryset based on this version field so that versions are ordered correctly according to their major, minor, and patch numbers.
class Release(models.Model):
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    release_version = models.CharField(max_length=16)

Using the default order_by gives the result in lexicographic order and it sorts 1.10.0 before 1.2.0  when sorting ascending. The solution seems to be that I can annotate the major, minor and patch version and then sort based on these three fields. The issue in this is that I am not able to figure out how to separate this version into major, minor and patch numbers.
I am using postgresql.

Have you looked into split?

What database do you use?

@willeM_VanOnsem I am using postgres

@ScottHunter I can  split the value but how can I do it in annotate for all the queryset.

This question is similar to: Order by split string django orm. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

To properly sort release_version field, you can break it down into major, minor, and patch numbers and sort them accordingly.
You can achieve this by using Django's annotate() feature, which allows you to annotate fields to perform operations on them, and SplitPart from PostgreSQL, which can split strings based on a delimiter.
This is the code example.
from django.db.models import F, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Cast
from django.db.models.expressions import Func
from django.db.models import IntegerField

queryset = Release.objects.annotate(
    major=Cast(Func(F('release_version'), Value('.'), Value(1), function='split_part'), IntegerField()),
    minor=Cast(Func(F('release_version'), Value('.'), Value(2), function='split_part'), IntegerField()),
    patch=Cast(Func(F('release_version'), Value('.'), Value(3), function='split_part'), IntegerField())
).order_by('major', 'minor', 'patch')

I hope this will solve your issue.
